# Cannot use Locust as a library in Django test framework

Tags: django, testing, locust

I want to use Locust as a library in Django's Unittest framework, because I want Django (3.1.2) to create a temporary database for me to do the testing. However, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py", line 104, in handle
    failures = TestRunner(test_labels, **options)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/django_test_runner.py", line 254, in run_tests
    return DjangoTeamcityTestRunner(**options).run_tests(test_labels,
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/django_test_runner.py", line 156, in run_tests
    return super(DjangoTeamcityTestRunner, self).run_tests(test_labels, extra_tests, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 695, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 614, in setup_databases
    return _setup_databases(
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 170, in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 57, in create_test_db
    self.connection.close()
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 285, in close
    self.validate_thread_sharing()
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 552, in validate_thread_sharing
    raise DatabaseError(
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object with alias 'default' was created in thread id 4487204352 and this is thread id 4528855696.
```

I don't seem to be able to even import Locust, for example, the following `test_locust.py`, which does nothing, can already reproduce the error:

```
from django.test import TransactionTestCase

from locust.env import Environment

class MyTestCase(TransactionTestCase):

    def test_cart(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful? https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/879 Try importing locust first and see if that makes a difference. The issue is probably related to gevent.

Comment: @Cyberwiz Thanks. It does seem to be a related issue. Importing Locust first does not help :( , but I wonder if I should open a ticket with Locust...

Comment: No point in opening a ticket with locust, seems like the issue is with gevent + django. Nothing locust can do about it..